# Debian dpkg error > libxrender1

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libxrender1 : Breaks: libxrender1:i386 (!= 1:0.9.7-1+deb7u1) but 1:0.9.7-1+deb7u1+b1 is installed
 libxrender1:i386 : Breaks: libxrender1 (!= 1:0.9.7-1+deb7u1+b1) but 1:0.9.7-1+deb7u1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.



apt-get -f install

> # apt-get -f install                                                                                                                                                                                             
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libasyncns0:i386 libaudio2:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libavcodec53:i386 libavutil51:i386 libcap2:i386 libcups2:i386
  libdbus-1-3:i386 libdirac-encoder0:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi5:i386 libflac8:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgcrypt11:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgnutls26:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libgsm1:i386
  libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 libice6:i386 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjpeg62 libjpeg8:i386 libjson0:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-3:i386
  libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms1:i386 libmng1:i386 libmp3lame0:i386 libogg0:i386 libopenjpeg2:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpcre3:i386 libpng12-0:i386 libpulse0:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386
  libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-xml:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqtdbus4:i386 libqtgui4:i386 libqtwebkit4:i386 libsamplerate0:i386 libschroedinger-1.0-0:i386 libsm6:i386 libsndfile1:i386 libspeex1:i386
  libspeexdsp1:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libtasn1-3:i386 libtheora0:i386 libtiff4:i386 libva1:i386 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libvpx1:i386 libwrap0:i386 libx11-6:i386
  libx11-xcb1:i386 libx264-123:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxi6:i386 libxml2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxss1:i386 libxt6:i386 libxtst6:i386 libxv1:i386 libxvidcore4:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libxrender1 libxrender1:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libxrender1 libxrender1:i386
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 133 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/65.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Reading changelogs... Done
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

edit:

If I try:

```
apt-get remove --purge libxrender1:i386
```

It just gives me the same error as above.

Any suggestions how I could solve that problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug. See [Debian bug report 782505](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=782505).

Briefly, this is a security fix gone wrong.
Less briefly, the package libxrender1 for the archs i386 and amd64 have different contents for the shared changelog file
`/usr/share/doc/libxrender1/changelog.Debian.gz`. This is of course not allowed by `dpkg`.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=782505#17 has a suggestion for a temporary workaround that worked for me. 
A possibly simpler alternative is suggested by https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=782505#27, namely apt pinning.

This will hopefully be fixed by the security team soon.

Comment: It's already fixed, `libxrender1` 1:0.9.7-1+deb7u2 was uploaded to `stable-security` on Monday.

Comment: @StephenKitt Oh, good to know.

Comment: Alright thanks for info but how can I solve this now?

Comment: @auL5agoi Actually, looking at your question, there might be something else going on. Can you paste into your question the output of `echo $PATH` as root?

Comment: @FaheemMitha thank you for the hint, I copied my .zshrc into my root folder where there is another $PATH defined but that didn't do anything to the error, I just ran it with sudo with the same outcome.

Comment: @auL5agoi well, Ok, but what is the answer to the question? What do you get for `echo $PATH`? And if you want to hop into the U&L chat room  , http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux it might be a bit faster. If you do, please ping me from there.

Comment: I can't explain what happend but I just typed the commands above again into the shell and suddenly everything is working fine.

Comment: @FaheemMitha : /root/.node/bin:/root/.node/bin:/root/.rbenv/bin:/root/.rbenv/bin:/home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/home/alex/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/alex/scripts:/git:/home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p4

Comment: @auL5agoi Wow, that's a lot of stuff. Is this the output of `echo $PATH` for root? If so, please add it to the question. Your errors above seemed to be stemming from the fact that `/sbin` was not in your path. If you alter the `PATH` variable, be sure that you don't remove stuff. Looking at your output, I don't see `/sbin/`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha, thank you I just removed all that stuff from the .root's .zshrc now there aren't any errors anymore, except the main error, however I just typed apt-get -f install again and it's gone, therefore I'm going to accept your answer.

Comment: Ok, fyi, the PATH is set in `/etc/profile` on Debian, and in general you want to avoid messing with it, and certainly overwriting it. In general, adding to it is OK, but that should be done sparingly. I have personally no additions to my PATH.